# Find any form element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find if a class exists and if not just find the first form element. How do I write :input? This does not seem to work.

```
$('.focus:not(:hidden):first, :input:not(:hidden):first').focus();
```

Comment: Why `:not(':hidden')`, when you could just use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)?

Comment: jquery selectors can't handle `if/else`. what you're doing is an `and`

Comment: this actually seems to work... what is your issue?

Comment: your code works. see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma-separated selectors are not hierarchical in the manner you seem to indicate. Your selector will yield the first visible `.focus` *and* the first visible input element. You'll need to break this up in two selectors:

```
var focusElement = $('.focus:visible:first');

if(focusElement.length == 0)
    focusElement = $(':input:visible:first');

focusElement.focus();
```

Or I suppose you could write

```
$('.focus:visible:first, body:not(:has(.focus:visible)) :input:visible:first').focus();
```

Comment: It's a terrible read, though, isn't it? I think I prefer the former, in terms of being able to read the code and actually understand the intent of the programmer writing it.

Comment: Oh, agreed; that line *needs* commenting to explain the *why*. Though the *what* is simple enough to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually worked for me. Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/uBypr/1/). Try removing my `class='focus'` and it then falls back to selecting the first input field.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the easy to understand model:

```
var finder = $('.focus:not(:hidden):first');
finder = finder.length ? finder: $(':input:not(:hidden):first');
finder.focus();
```

Same result, but likely better given the right to left sizzle re: performance

```
var finder = $('.focus').not(':hidden').eq(0);
finder = finder.length ? finder: $(':input').not(':hidden').eq(0);
finder.focus();
```